# Returning a default value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to return a default value if no such record exists for the given parameters. Here's the sql query:

```
DECLARE @List VARCHAR(max) 
DECLARE @date VARCHAR(max)
SET @List = '''4401366'',''3115880'''
SET @date = '''2018-02-09 00:00:00.000'''
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(max)
SET @SQL = N'
select  EmpNo,  attendanceStatus =

CASE 
WHEN AttDate is null then ''false''
WHEN max(AttTimeIn) is null and max(AttTimeOut) is null THEN ''false''
WHEN max(AttTimeIn) is not null and max(AttTimeOut) is not null then(case when (max(AttTimeIn) < max(AttTimeOut)) then ''false'' else ''true'' end)
WHEN max(AttTimeIn) is not null and max(AttTimeOut) is null  THEN ''true''
else ''false''
end

from tablename
where empNo in (' +@list+ ')  AND AttDate = ('+ @date +')
group by EmpNo, AttDate'

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL
```

To be more specific, i want attendanceStatus to return false in case no such record exists for the given date (for each employee). How can I achieve this?

Comment: any error in the code?\

Comment: So in your result set, you want all `empNo` in tablename? In other words, the number of rows in the result set would be the same number as `select count(distinct empNo) from tablename`?

Comment: use `PRINT @SQL` to see the query and check if thats doing what you want

Comment: @HoneyBadger EXACTLY.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need something like this, but without data it is difficult to test:

```
SET @SQL = N'
SELECT      T0.EmpNo
,           attendanceStatus = CASE 
                                    WHEN T1.empNo is null 
                                        THEN ''false''
                                    WHEN max(T1.AttTimeIn) is null and max(T1.AttTimeOut) is null 
                                        THEN ''false''
                                    WHEN max(T1.AttTimeIn) is not null and max(T1.AttTimeOut) is not null 
                                        THEN(CASE WHEN (max(T1.AttTimeIn) < max(T1.AttTimeOut)) 
                                                THEN ''false'' else ''true'' END)
                                    WHEN max(T1.AttTimeIn) is not null and max(T1.AttTimeOut) is null  
                                        THEN ''true''
                                        ELSE ''false''
                                END
FROM        tablename T0
LEFT JOIN   tablename T1
        ON  T1.empNo = T0.empNo
        AND T1.AttDate = ('+ @date +')
WHERE       T0.empNo in (' +@list+ ')  
GROUP BY    T0.EmpNo
,           T1.AttDate
'
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this.

```
DECLARE @List VARCHAR(max) 
DECLARE @date VARCHAR(max)
SET @List = '''4401366'',''3115880'''
SET @date = '''2018-02-09 00:00:00.000'''
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(max)
SET @SQL = N'
select  EmpNo,  attendanceStatus =
    CASE WHEN AttDate = ('+ @date +') THEN 
        CASE 
            WHEN max(AttTimeIn) is null and max(AttTimeOut) is null THEN ''false''
            WHEN max(AttTimeIn) is not null and max(AttTimeOut) is not null then(case when (max(AttTimeIn) < max(AttTimeOut)) then ''false'' else ''true'' end)
            WHEN max(AttTimeIn) is not null and max(AttTimeOut) is null  THEN ''true''
            ELSE ''false''
        END
    ELSE ''false'' END
from tablename
where empNo in (' +@list+ ')  
group by EmpNo, AttDate'

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL
```

Answer (score 0):

this should work

```
DECLARE @List VARCHAR(max) 
DECLARE @date VARCHAR(max)
SET @List = '''4401366'',''3115880'''
SET @date = '''2018-02-09 00:00:00.000'''
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(max)
SET @SQL = N'
--check if employee exists
with empTable as (
SELECT DISTINCT EmpNo
FROM tablename
WHERE empNo in (' +@list+ '))

select  Et.EmpNo,  attendanceStatus =

CASE 
WHEN T.AttDate is null then ''false''
WHEN max(T.AttTimeIn) is null and max(T.AttTimeOut) is null THEN ''false''
WHEN max(T.AttTimeIn) is not null and max(T.AttTimeOut) is not null then(case when (max(T.AttTimeIn) < max(T.AttTimeOut)) then ''false'' else ''true'' end)
WHEN max(T.AttTimeIn) is not null and max(T.AttTimeOut) is null  THEN ''true''
else ''false''
end

from 
empTable eT 
LEFT JOIN tablename T ON
    et.EmpNo=T.EmpNo
where T.AttDate = ('+ @date +')
group by et.EmpNo, T.AttDate'

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL
```

Answer (score 0):

I have rewritten your code, simplified your *case statement* and removed some code

```
AttDate is null then 'false'
```

AttDate will never be null because it is included in the *where clause*

I also changed the data type for *@date* and made it into a parameterized query for date. Your script is still prone to sql injection because of *@List*. This can be avoided by splitting it into a table.

I am not sure what you want to replace with a default value. But here is the improved script:

```
DECLARE @List VARCHAR(max) 
DECLARE @date DATE
SET @List = '''4401366'',''3115880'''
SET @date = '2018-02-09'
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(max)
SET @SQL = N'
  SELECT coalesce(EmpNo, ''default'') EmpNo,
  CASE WHEN i is not null and (i >= o or o is null) THEN ''true'' ELSE ''false'' END
  FROM
  (
    SELECT
      Empno,
      max(AttTimeIn) over (partition by EmpNo) i,
      max(AttTimeOut) over (partition by EmpNo)o
    FROM tablename  
    WHERE empNo in (' +@list+ ')  AND AttDate = @date
    GROUP BY EmpNo, AttDate
  ) x
  GROUP BY EmpNo'

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, N'@date date', @date
```